# getting the images that load in a page dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, tampermonkey

I'd like to get all the images in a facebook newsfeed as it is loaded. I'm running a  tampermonkey script. I'm having a few problems:

1. the end result is including in the images with urls that I'm excluding (with facebook static urls).
2. it only includes some of the images in the newsfeed, and if i scroll down it does not re-evaluate its outputs. This is probably because of the load function, but how can I make it a dynamic load instead? Where could I add a function like .scroll for example?

I'm using jquery to run the functions only when the page is loaded. Should I do something else instead?

Below is some part of the code:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Accountability
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @include     https://www.facebook.com/*
// @include     http*://*.facebook.com/*
// @exclude       htt*://*static*.facebook.com*
// @version      0.1
// @description  
// @author       You
// @match        http://tampermonkey.net/scripts.php
// @grant        none
// @require http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js
// ==/UserScript==
/* jshint -W097 */
'use strict';

 window.addEventListener('load', function() {

var all_images = document.evaluate('//img[@src]', document, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null); 
var newsfeed = document.evaluate('//*[contains(@id, topnews_main_stream_408239535924329)]', document, null,XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null); 

var imgSrcs = [];
for (var i=0; i < all_images.snapshotLength; i++){
    var this_image = all_images.snapshotItem(i);
    var src = this_image.src;
    if(src.indexOf('static') > -1){
        continue;
    }
    if(src.indexOf('external') > -1){
        continue;
    }
    imgSrcs.push(src);
    console.log(this_image.src);
    this_image.addEventListener("click", my_func, false);
}

for (var i=0; i < newsfeed.snapshotLength; i++){
    var this_news = newsfeed.snapshotItem(i);
    var src = this_news.src;
    if(this_news.children.length>0){
        }
    if(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(this_news)[0]== '_startTime'){ 
        var x = this_news.onreadystatechange();
        }   
    this_news.addEventListener("click", my_func, false);
    this_news.addEventListener("mouseover", my_func, false);
}
var my_func = function(){
    console.log("the list", imgSrcs);
}

}, false);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can bind `load` on all `img` tags like

```
$("img").on("load", function() {
  console.log($(this)[0].src)
});
```

If you really want to use pure javascript to mimic `on`, you can reference [Emulate jQuery "on" with selector in pure javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14677019/emulate-jquery-on-with-selector-in-pure-javascript)